# Calculating Japan Accrued Tax for IRS Form 1116?

Tags: japan, income-tax

Does anyone know how do I calculate my accrued Japanese taxes from a US Form 1116 perspective? Or general guidelines that apply to most major countries? How would a CPA actually know to figure this out? Does the IRS publish a list somewhere?

- Taxable Income (源泉徴収税額)
- Inhabitants Taxes (住民税)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Japanese taxes specifically, but the IRS does publish general guidelines as to what taxes qualify. The full publication is [here](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/what-foreign-taxes-qualify-for-the-foreign-tax-credit).

> Generally, the following four tests must be met for any foreign tax to qualify for the credit:
>
> - The tax must be imposed on you
> - You must have paid or accrued the tax
> - The tax must be the legal and actual foreign tax liability
> - The tax must be an income tax (or a tax in lieu of an income tax)

So for example, property taxes or sales taxes would not qualify.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a cash-basis US taxpayer and your financial year is January 1 through December 31 (most US taxpayers satisfy these conditions), then for the purpose of Form 1116 for Year X, the foreign income tax that you paid for Year X is the *total* of

- income tax withheld from your foreign wages or other foreign income during Year X

*plus*

- any income tax paid during Year X as estimated tax payments,

*plus*

- any income tax paid during Year X with the final tax return for previous years' income taxes,

*minus*

- any refunds of income tax received during Year X.